# Numerical precision in python

Tags: python, numerical-analysis

I've been doing simple numerical experiments with python, like computing
factorials. For instance, compute the factorial of 32:

My routine:

```
2.6313083693369503e+35
```

From scipy.misc:

```
2.6313083693369355e+35
```

I want to point out that my routine calculates the logarithm of the factorial,
it calculates the sumation of logarithms starting from 1 to 32 (in this case)
and then I just take the exp function (I do it this way because of stuff learned from
Fortran 90).

It is a surprise that the correct answer is

```
263130836933693530167218012160000000
```

according to pari/gp.

I would be very happy if someone can point me out to references where I can look for
correct numerical answers in Python. The documentation it's ok but only if one want 
"short" numbers.

Comment: It would be appreciated if you could provide the code of your routine.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for.  You reimplemented `math.factorial` using `float` precision, and then threw a bit more precision away by moving in and out of log space, and wound up with a few digits' worth of error at the end.  Python doesn't really have anything to do with this, you'd have the same issue using double precision in fortran.

Comment: If you are dealing with integers, python gives you big integers, so you can brute-force compute the factorial exactly.

Answer (score 0):

`log` and `exp` functions operate on floating points, which have limited precision. Python's integers, on the other hand, can have arbitrary precision. So, you can compute the factorial of 32 in linear space just fine using integers.

```
f = 1
for i in xrange(32):
    f *= i + 1
print f  # prints '263130836933693530167218012160000000'
```

Comment: Ok this is good to know.
And the reason of doing it with floats is that the factorial of a number grows really fast, and that's why sometimes is better to calculate it with float numbers.
Doing them with integers can be too naive as I experienced in the past.

Comment: @user2820579 You have to decide: Precision or speed. You can't have both.

Comment: Floats are fast because they have limited precision. As @Hyperboreus says, it's a trade-off.

Comment: It will suit me precision, since I'm doing numerical computation. Also: _Because the Gamma and factorial functions grow so rapidly for moderately large arguments, many computing environments include a function that returns the natural logarithm of the gamma function_ [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function]. This is why I was trying for logs...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
import operator
n=32
print reduce(operator.__mul__,range(1,n+1))
# 263130836933693530167218012160000000
```